# Multi mapping in dapper.net

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm implementing my first [Dapper.Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) project. Now i'm wondering what's the easiest way to initialize an object that contains another object(multi mapping).

Here's my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<ShopPrefix> GetShopPrefixes(short fiSL)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.RM2Con))
    {
        const String sql = @"
            SELECT  locShopPrefix.idShopPrefix,
                    locShopPrefix.fiSL,
                    locShopPrefix.fiShop,
                    locShopPrefix.Prefix,
                    locShopPrefix.Active,
                    locShop.idShop,
                    locShop.ShopName,
                    locShop.ContactPerson,
                    locShop.Street,
                    locShop.ZIP,
                    locShop.City,
                    locShop.Telephone,
                    locShop.Telefax,
                    locShop.Email,
                    locShop.ShopKey
            FROM    locShopPrefix
                    INNER JOIN locShop
                        ON locShopPrefix.fiShop = locShop.idShop
            WHERE   (locShopPrefix.fiSL = @fiSL);";
        con.Open();
        IEnumerable<Tuple<ShopPrefix,Shop>> shops =
            con.Query<ShopPrefix, Shop, Tuple<ShopPrefix, Shop>>(
            sql
            , (shopPrefix, shop) => Tuple.Create(shopPrefix, shop)
            , new { fiSL = fiSL }, splitOn: "idShop"
        );
        foreach (var shop in shops)
            shop.Item1.Shop = shop.Item2;
        return shops.Select(t => t.Item1);
    }
}
```

So every `shopPrefix` belongs to (has) a `Shop`.

**Q:** Is this the correct way to map two objects since the `Tuple` approach with the following `foreach` to initialize the property `Shop` looks cumbersome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need a `IEnumerable<Tuple<>>` for a simple One-To-One object relationship.
The following snippet should be sufficient as well.

```
var shopsPrefixes = con.Query<ShopPrefix, Shop, ShopPrefix>(sql
    , (shopPrefix, shop) =>
    {
        shopPrefix.Shop = shop;
        return shopPrefix;
    }
    , new { fiSL = fiSL }
    , splitOn: "idShop"
);
return shopsPrefixes;
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, that looks promising but now i'm getting _"When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id"_. With the `Tuple` it worked. I'll modify your answer to show what i've changed (i need the `ShopPrefixes` instead of the `Shops`).

Comment: How does your DTO look exactly? If ShopPrefix is a child of Shop, I think you have to define the following as for the query types : Query<Shop, ShopPrefix, Shop>. I'm not sure if Dapper can do an inverse mapping from Child to Parent :)

Comment: Every `ShopPrefix` belongs to/has a `Shop`(FK in DB) whereas a `Shop` can have multiple prefixes. I want to initialize (possibly multiple) `ShopPrefix` with their related `Shop`.

Comment: You're right, only the order was wrong. So this works: `con.Query<ShopPrefix, Shop, ShopPrefix>`(the same order as in my original query). Thank you very much.